# Triangular Vertices - Lua calculation?

Tags: lua

I am current determined to complete a problem in Lua and have no idea where to begin. I was thinking about beginning with a modulus operator. I am searching for advice from experienced Lua programmers on how to program this and mainly how I can calculate the theoretically mathematical side of the problem.

[Source of the question... (http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~pbo/ACM/archive/00209.html)](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~pbo/ACM/archive/00209.html)

Gratitude will be shown to anyone who answers correctly.
Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_left(max)
    i = 0
    j = 1
    ls = {}

    repeat
        i = i + 1
        j = j + i - 1
        ls[i] = j
        print (ls[i], " ls")
    until j >= max

    return ls
end

a = get_left(27)
```

(need to format that as code -.-)

```
if the point1 is between a[i] and a[i+1]
if then point2 is still between a[i] and a[i+1] it is on the same line
else if point2 is between a[i + n] and a[i + n + 1]
then if point2 is at a[i + n] + (a[i] - point1) + n + 1 its in a strait line right above it
else if point2 is at a[i + n] + (a[i] - point1) + n - 1 its in a strait line left above it

if for all points n or n*(-1) is equal the distance between the points is equal.
```

That is if I didn't make any logical errors and you probably have to check more for it to work properly.

This is more a mathematical question than lua I recommend adding a math tag to it.